# Makefile trouble, getting "recipe for target 'rgbapixel.o' failed"

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm having some trouble as I'm fairly new to C++ and Makefiles

My Makefile looks like this:

```
EXENAME = testimage
OBJS = rgbapixel.o png.o image.o testimage.o 

CXX = clang++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -std=c++0x -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -c -g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic
LD = clang++
LDFLAGS = -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -lpng -lc++abi

all: $(EXENAME)

$(EXENAME) : $(OBJS)
    $(LD) $(OBJS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $(EXENAME)

png.o : png.cpp png.h rgbapixel.h image.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) png.cpp

image.o : image.cpp image.h png.h rgbapixel.h 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) c++ image.cpp 

rgbapixel.o : rgbapixel.cpp rgbapixel.h 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) rgbapixel.cpp

testimage.cpp : image.h png.h rgbapixel.h png.o
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) c++ testimage.cpp -o testimage

clean : 
    -rm -f *.o $(EXENAME)
```

And I'm getting this as feedback from the terminal:

```
clang++ -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -lc++abi -std=c++0x -std=c++11 -std=gnu++11 -c -g -O0 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic rgbapixel.cpp
clang: error: -lc++abi: 'linker' input unused
Makefile:21: recipe for target 'rgbapixel.o' failed
make: *** [rgbapixel.o] Error 1
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction for what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are passing linker command line flags to a compilation command. `clang++` appears to be throwing an error for that. Don't put the linker flags in your `CXXFLAGS`.

Answer (score 0):

`-lc++abi` should be removed from `CXXFLAGS`